# GoogleSheets: How to write a script to automatically create a new tab, or delete/rename an existing tab, based on a list?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

any help for what I need to do below is greatly appreciated!

I have a main tab in Google Sheet with a list of employees name in Column A.

I'm adding, removing, and renaming cells in this column very often.

When I input new values into an empty cell in Column A, I want it to create a new tab, named after the value I input.

When I empty/delete a cell, I want it to delete the tab associated with it.

When I rename a cell, I want it to rename the tab associated with it as well.

Here's an example

Main tab:

```
    | Col A |
  1 |  Bob  |
  2 |  Bill |
  3 |  Abby |
  4 | Cathy |
  5 | Jill  |
  6 |       |
  7 |       |
```

Employee Tabs:

```
Bob, Bill, Abby, Cathy, Jill
```

Then, I delete row 5 (the whole row), and added 3 more names below Cathy:

```
    | Col A |
  1 |  Bob  |
  2 |  Bill |
  3 |  Abby |
  4 | Cathy |
  5 | Rosie |
  6 |  Jack |
  7 | Matt  |
```

Now I have the following Employee Tabs:

```
Bob, Bill, Abby, Cathy, Rosie, Jack, Matt
```

Then, Abby decided to change her name to Abs
        | Col A |
      1 |  Bob  |
      2 |  Bill |
      3 |  Ab   |
      4 | Cathy |
      5 | Rosie |
      6 |  Jack |
      7 | Matt  |

Now here are my Employee Tabs:

```
Bob, Bill, Ab, Cathy, Rosie, Jack, Matt
```

Comment: You can bind the event object of a spreadsheet's edit event, which will allow you to inspect the previous and current values of the edited cell. (Note that multi cell edits will not include the event value.) After you know which cell was edited and the previous and current values, it is a simple matter to modify the spreadsheets' sheets.

Answer (score 0):

## Create, Rename and Delete Sheets/Tabs

```
function createTab() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet('sheetName');
}

function renameTab() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('currentname').setName('newName')
}

function deleteTab() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().deleteSheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SheetName'));
}
```

- [Spreadsheet Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleteSheet(Sheet))
- [Sheet Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)